# Recuperar Lista do model passados por ajax através FormData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, formdata

Estou enviando uma imagem, junto com um model no qual contém uma lista de inteiros.

Porém não estou conseguindo recuperar no momento que entra na
Action. consigo recuperar a imagem, campo1 e campo2, já o campo campoLista fica em branco.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="profilePic" name="file" value="Browse">
```

**JS**

```
var data = new FormData();
var files = $("#profilePic").get(0).files;

data.append("Image", files[0]); 
data.append("grupo[campo1]", "A");
data.append("grupo[campo2]", "B");
data.append("grupo[campoLista]", "1,2,3");
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: '/Home/Index',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    contentType: false, // Not to set any content header  
    processData: false, // Not to process data  
    success: function(response) { 
   },
    error: function() { alert('A error'); }
});
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(Grupo grupo){

var parCampo1 = grupo.campo1;
var parCampo2 = grupo.campo2;
var parCampoLista = grupo.campoLista;

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
{

    var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Image"];

    if (pic != null)
    {
        Session["ImgPath"] = "~/Content/Uploads/" + pic.FileName;
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/");
        pic.SaveAs(path + pic.FileName);
    }
}
 }
```

**Model**

```
public class Grupo
{
    public string campo1 { get; set; }
    public string campo2 { get; set; }
    public List<int> campoLista { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
data.append("grupo[campoLista]", "1,2,3");
```

Você está passando como uma string e não como um array.

Pelo que entendi o formData.append não suporta JSON, por isso meu exemplo anterior não funcionou usando o JSON.stringify(). Teste dessa forma:

```js
var campoLista = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
let formData = new FormData();

jQuery.each(campoLista, function(key, value) {
    formData.append('campoLista['+key+']', value);
});

console.log(campoLista);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ainda vem em branco. porém no data.append está certo, fiz uma verificação com: 
   * for (var pair of data.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
    } *   Agora não faço idéia porque não sai lá no controller.

Comment: Veja agora com a edição que fiz.

Comment: Agora sim ! Obrigado @George Wurthmann